# How do I create a imageview like this?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I create a imageview like the one circled in the pic. New to this android app coding ;3. Any help is appreciated ^-^

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5C9.jpg)

Comment: Its not a button!. ImageView

Comment: oh my bad >.< sorry still new into this..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this isn't button it's called Cardview
- Make item to as cardview sample (template) like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

       <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_tv_id"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Title Placed Here"
                android:textColor="@color/DodgerBlue4"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

then create receyclerviewer 
then fill it with cardview template by RecyclerView.Adapter